# Persist AdMob Ad State Across Activities & Navigation on Android

Tags: android, admob

To clarify I would like to re-use the same ad across multiple activities. I basically just want the ad to init & load on the first activity, then other activities to show already loaded ad. This way I can reduce amount of time ads spend loading as navigation is quick and ads dont have time to load across all activities.

I was thinking to store a reference to the AdView in the Application class, and have all other activities lazy-load from there. However in doing so I feel this may create a memory leak in a sense that AdView might hold a reference to the initial activity and that would prevent GC from cleaning out UI resources associated w/ that activity.

Wondering if there are any other work-arounds for tackling this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good solution that fits your exact question.
As you have surmised they will all leak memory.

The best course of action would be to use a single Activity with multiple Fragments that you switch between. Then you can have a single AdView Fragment that remains throughout.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/android/quick-start

Comment: Thanks, this solution echoed through other forums as well. Would you happen to have an example or  URL w/ sample code?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with AdViews**

The problem in referencing only one `Adview` is very tricky because `one ad view can only hold one unique ad unit`.

There's no proper documentation on how to reuse the ad or how to use multiple ad tags for the same ad view object. However, you can store `AdViews` in `Cache` and may be able to use it.

If you do wish to change the `ad unit` later, you will want to store the ads in the hash map with ad tag as the key and an array of ad views as the value. Reason is because you want at least 2 ad views in the cache. `AdViews` generally take a lot of memory since it's like webview based and some background rendering takes place once the `adunit` is loaded.

As far as viewing the same ad on other activities with the preloaded ad may not be possible cause once you use a ad view, `Load ad needs to be called to actually view an ad`.

Again, no code in this answer yet but if you do want a sample code to see how you can actually cache the AdView's and try to reuse them to make your app more memory efficient, please leave in the comments.